# How to upload NSData Object to server with specific name?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, post, nsurlrequest

How to upload NSData Object to server with specific name ?

```
NSData *imgData; // Image Data
NSString *imgName = @"myfile.png";
```

I want to upload data to server with specific file name.

```
1. Upload Data (imgData) 

2. To server (my_server.com/upload.html) 

3. With file name (imgName)
```

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a school project where I needed to do something similar to this...

I was placing longitude and latitude values in a database.

*MAKE NOTE THAT THERE MAY BE MUCH SIMPLER WAYS TO DO THIS. I AM BY NO MEANS A "PRO" AT OBJECTIVE-C PROGRAMMING*

There are going to be three things you need.

1. a server in which you have access to.
2. a PHP file that will write the data to the database.
3. an NSURLConnection object;

I had placed the following code in one of the delegate methods for CLLocationManager.

The NSURLConnection object should look something like this:

```
//this is where I put the url for my PHP file
url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/folder/example.php"]];

urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

Of course the variables: url, urlRequest, and connection are declared in the header file like this

```
NSURL *url;
NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
NSMutableData *filedata;
NSURLConnection *connection;
```